# How to add multiple Landsat image on GEE?

Tags: google-earth-engine, javascript, landsat-8

I want to use Landsat image from GEE with area specified within an input. But when I run the script it only shows a small part of the area (the intended area of interest is the one in blue). The code is as the following

```
var countries = Indonesia

var Nama_Provinsi = ['Kalimantan Selatan'] 
var geometry = countries.filter(ee.Filter.inList('NAME_1', Nama_Provinsi));
var area1 = ee.FeatureCollection(geometry);
Map.centerObject(geometry, 8);
Map.addLayer(geometry,{color:"Blue" },"Provinsi");

var L8 = ee.ImageCollection("LANDSAT/LC08/C01/T1_TOA")
var RGB_vis = {min: 0, max: 0.3, bands: ['B4', 'B3', 'B2']};
var filtered = L8
.filterDate('2020-01-01', '2020-12-31')
.filterBounds(geometry)
.sort('CLOUD_COVER', true);
var image = ee.Image(filtered.first());
Map.addLayer(image, RGB_vis,'RGB', false );

// Compute the Enhanced Vegetation Index (EVI).
var nir = image.select('B5');
var red = image.select('B4');
var blue = image.select('B2');
var evi = image.expression(
  '2.5*(B5-B4)/(B5+6*B4-7.5*B2+1)', {
    'B5' : nir,
    'B4' : red,
    'B2' : blue
  });
// Display the result.
Map.centerObject(image, 8);
var eviPara ={min: -1, max: 1, palette: ['blue', 'white', 'green']};
Map.addLayer(evi, eviPara, 'EVI');
```

And the result I got is as the picture.
[image]

Answer (score 1):

```js
var image = ee.Image(filtered.first());
```

In this line you are asking for **only one image from the collection** that matches your filters. To get coverage of the entire area, you must consult multiple images. A common way to do this is with the `.mosaic()` operation, which layers the images “on top of” each other (last on top, so most recent on top if not sorted).

```js
var image = filtered.mosaic();
```

You can also use averages or other reduction operations; the median of all images in the collection is a common choice:

```js
var image = filtered.median();
```